# Is there a function that resets app to its initial stage?

Tags: swift, restore

I am building a calculator app and want to include Clear button. It would reset app to its initial startup stage. Is there a function that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function because the framework (Cocoa/Cocoa Touch) cannot know your application code. It is after all just a computer program and not a human. So what you have to do is write a method that resets all your calculator-relevant variables to initial values, preferably in your calculator's data model.

So for example you add a reset button and when the button is pressed it calls your reset method where you reset all your data values (probably the calculated result, etc.). After that you reset your UI based on the initialised data.